# apache server keeps crashing on ubunutu, ssl: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, vhosts

i have a windows machine and have ubuntu as a guest OS on VM. i set up apache onubuntu and im trying to configure ssl on that server but apache keeps crashing after following all instructions i found on the internet.
I have my ssl files in 
/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

I have a default-ssl conf file with:
DocumentRoot /var/www-ssl/html/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

In the vhost and I also have the same in a vhost i am setting up(forums) forums-ssl conf file.
Mod ssl is already enabled

In my guest host file I have: 127.0.0.1       localhost test tribunal

When I restart apache, it asks me for my pass phrase, I enter it and it says ok, although it spits out those notices. But when I navigate to the page it times out.

and here is the error in apache error_log:
[Sun Mar 04 20:23:59 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 04 20:24:04 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.7 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations

does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: have you solved this issue?